# Is it common to use 'time slot' to refer to days/weeks?

Tags: word-usage, business-language

How would you say to a client that you a have a 'free time slot' (like days or weeks) to take a job? Is it common to refer to 'time slot' even if I'm thinking about days or even weeks?

Comment: A ***time slot***  is a time assigned on a schedule or agenda; "the TV program has a new time slot"; "an aircraft landing slot"
A ***slot*** is an 
interval, time interval - a definite length of time marked off by two instants.    http://www.thefreedictionary.com/time+slot I think you mean   that they can start at their best  convenience,

Comment: Yes, but the whole point is pushing the client to accept the quote right away, so we can start working now, because now it's slow at work, but eventually it will be not.

Comment: "If we start now, we can complete your project by XX. However, if we delay, we cannot guarantee the same turnaround time." Spell it out. It protects you from client confusion and also offers a paper trail if the client claims you reneged on what you said.

Comment: Also, for the short version, I think it would be fine to say *time slot".  "Time window", "window of opportunity" or "window" might perhaps be better for the longer time intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time slot, is a regular time during the day, it may be several hours, however, never longer than 8 hours. In general a time slot more or less an hour, and you may set more than one aside for something. A time slot is recurring daily, weekly or monthly.